# Multiple conditions in xstring

Tags: formatting, conditionals, xstring

This is potentially a very noob question, but how could one use multiple conditions when parsing with xstring?

The accepted answer that I'm linking below, shows how one can align complex numbers in a table. 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83639/118726
I want the complex numbers to be allowed to be of the form `a+ib` but also `a-ib`. 
I need to modify the line

> \StrBefore{#1}{+}[\RealPart]%

to look for the string before + OR -.

Any ideas?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{collcell}

\sisetup{
output-complex-root = \ensuremath{\mathrm{i}},
complex-root-position = before-number
}

\newlength{\WidestRealNum}
\settowidth{\WidestRealNum}{$99999$}
\newcommand*{\ApplyNumFormatting}[1]{%
    \StrBefore{#1}{+}[\RealPart]%
    \StrBehind{#1}{i}[\ImagPart]%
    $\makebox[\WidestRealNum][r]{$\RealPart$} + i\,\ImagPart$%
}%

\newcolumntype{N}{>{\collectcell\ApplyNumFormatting}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Some complex numbers }
\label{table:Fhkl}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ N S[]}
    \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{N column  } &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S[] column}\\
        \midrule
     -774.66 - i 325.61    & -774.66 - i 325.61   \\
     774.66 - i 325.61     & 774.66 - i 325.61   \\
     -151.85 + i 325.61    & -151.85 + i 325.61    \\
     151.85 + i 325.61     & 151.85 + i 325.61    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%


\end{document}
```

The S[] type is indeed a solution but I do prefer the center alignment of the sign. You can see below the N format as it is now fails for anything other than a+ib or -a+ib.

[image: mwe table of complex numbers]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Why don't you use the `S` column added by `siunitx`? It is good that you linked the answer, but it would've been better if you posted a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: The `listofitems` package can parse based on multiple separators (e.g., `\setsepchar{+||-}`).  Not sure if it can be leveraged for your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but here is what I have so far, based on the solution linked above. I actually tweaked this solution starting from the idea suggested by @koleygr:

> If these is a '+' then Real part is before the '+'. If there is no '+' check if there are two '-'s. If there are two '-'s the Real part is before the second '-', else it is before the first '-'.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{collcell}

\sisetup{
output-complex-root = \ensuremath{\mathrm{i}},
complex-root-position = before-number
}


\newlength{\WidestRealNum}
\settowidth{\WidestRealNum}{$99999$}
\newcommand*{\ApplyNumFormatting}[1]{%
\IfSubStr{#1}{+}{%
    \StrBefore{#1}{+}[\RealPart]}{%
    \IfSubStr[2]{#1}{-}{%
        \StrBefore[2]{#1}{-}[\RealPart]}{%
        \StrBefore{#1}{-}[\RealPart]}%
   }
 \StrBehind{#1}{i}[\ImagPart]%

\IfSubStr{#1}{+}{%
    $\makebox[\WidestRealNum][r]{$\RealPart$} + i\,\ImagPart$}{%
    $\makebox[\WidestRealNum][r]{$\RealPart$} - i\,\ImagPart$}
}%


\newcolumntype{N}{>{\collectcell\ApplyNumFormatting}l<{\endcollectcell}}
```

And the table is:

[image: table of complex numbers]

Comment: Welcome Elena, nice solution.... You may add `\IfStreq` conditions as second solution (xstring's other command) using your own checks and I am going to delete my solution ... (just added for pluralism for now) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `\IfStrEq` command. The idea is that if "+" is not found by `\StrBefore` command, then the optional argument `\RealPart` will remain empty... I use this case in an `\IfStrEq` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{collcell}

\sisetup{
    output-complex-root = \ensuremath{\mathrm{j}},
    complex-root-position = before-number
}

\newlength{\WidestRealNum}
\settowidth{\WidestRealNum}{$99999$}
\newcommand*{\ApplyNumFormatting}[1]{%
\gdef\msign{+}%
    \StrBefore{#1}{\msign}[\RealPart]\IfStrEq{\RealPart}{}{\gdef\msign{-}\StrBefore{#1}{\msign}[\RealPart]}{}%
    \StrBehind{#1}{j}[\ImagPart]%
    $\makebox[\WidestRealNum][r]{$\RealPart$} \msign j\,\ImagPart$%
}%
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\collectcell\ApplyNumFormatting}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Bus Loads}
    \label{fig:figurename}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l|N}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Bus} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Bus Load (MVA)}} \\
        \midrule
            b1 &  50 + j 30.99 \\
            b2 & 170 + j105.35\\
            b3 & 200 - j123.94 \\
            b4 & 150 + j49.58 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Just as another fast fix and idea just for your problem (But @ElenasPascal answer is more complete and she has +1 from me)

Comment: I like it as an alternative for the above issue; the problem is now that both of these fail for -a-ib... Back to the drawing board